# How to go to a program directory?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to go to a program directory (e.g. git). `where git | cd` does not work, because it returns a file instead of folder. What is the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: Firstly you have your `cd` and `where git` around the wrong way. You need to find out where `git` is and pipe that into `cd`, at the moment you are piping the output of `cd` (which with no options would just tell you the current directory) into the `where` command.

Comment: He means, `where git|cd`.

Comment: `cd` does not accept input via pipe. It also never has.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do it from a CMD file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where %1') do cd /d "%%~dPi."
```

or you can eliminate the WHERE command altogether, since cmd has a similar feature already built in:

```
cd /d "%~dP$PATH:1."
```

Put the preferred line in a CMD file in your path, like FindExe.cmd, and then just run `findexe calc.exe`.
If you want to run it interactively from the command line (not in a CMD file), I think you're stuck with:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('where calc.exe') do cd /d "%~dPi."
```

.. substituting *calc.exe* with the appropriate command.

In case you're wondering, the way you attempted doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `WHERE` returns the full path including the file name.  You don't want the file name.
2. `cd` does not accept piped input.

Comment: Do you have a reference for using `$PATH` with `for`?

Comment: It's in the help for the `for` command toward the end. (`for /?`)  I suspect it works for other variables as well besides `PATH`.  I skipped the FOR command altogether on that one, but the syntax is the same.  It may not be clear from my example, but `"%~dP$PATH:1` is operating on the `%1` argument passed to the CMD file.  I'm removing the mention of FOR in that part of the answer.

Comment: @GuitarPicker that is very interesting, but could you clarify how you get that $PATH line to work with %1 see http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HEviVCLm   where it doesn't work with %1  so how did you get it to work?

Comment: @barlop You have `$~dP$PATH:1` instead of `%~dp$PATH:1` (leading `$` instead of `%`

Comment: Neither of your variants will work if you are currently on a different drive to the one where the program is located. Use `cd /d` as pointed out by @barlop

Comment: @GuitarPicker: Any reason you're including the final period in `cd "%~dP$PATH:1."`?

Comment: I thought I was having a glitch earlier with cd not liking the trailing backslash.  It turns out I was mistaken and must have been having some other sort of problem.  This is a useful way to work around backslashes for programs that don't handle it.  It should be safe to remove them all or leave them in for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm editing my answer to put the "cd /d" in place.  I can't believe I skipped that part!

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I go to a program directory?

From the comand line:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a in (`where git`) do %~da && cd %~dpa
```

From a batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`where git`) do %%~da && cd %%~dpa
```

As per the comment from [barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop), the `do` part can be simplified from `%%~da && cd %%~dpa` to `cd /d %%~dpa`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script:

---

Comment: @DavidPostill  You can improve that `do cd /d %~dpa` but the combination you have `%~da && cd %~dpa` is good and interesting.

Comment: @PHPst  It'd be ideal if CMD supported something like CD expand(where git)  But it doesn't, and CMD instead has this very long command that can be used to set a variable to the output of a command. `for /f %f in ('echo abc') do set a=%f`     But you don't want CD blah\bleh\git.exe  that won't work  So if you have David's for line, and after the 'do' you put cd %~dpa  then it does CD to just the path.. and cd /d just makes cd work better, so if the path is on a different drive/partition then the cd will still work. If you do cd z:\blah  it won't work unless you do cd /d z:\blah

Comment: @PHPst but anyhow, the primary reason for the complexity. and most of the complexity, is the big for line, and that's because as mentioned, CMD doesn't support anything like cd 'command' and its alternative (for) is a rather laborious exercise in absurdity in length and uglyness and some trickyness. 'For' has a number of uses, it's a weird thing.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason for your preference in using usebackq? (as opposed to not doing usebackq, and using single quotes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22811/discussion-between-barlop-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 0):

using `for` modifiers only (quicker, more compact and also works if `where` is not available) and `pushd` so it's possible to go back to origin:
`for %i in (git.exe) do pushd  %~dp$PATH:i`

*(I just noticed GuitarPicker proposed similar, but not exactly the same, solution...)*